# jQuery loops unexpectedly with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I had an image slider that was working fine with solely html, but now that I have introduced PHP to generate the address for each image from a database, the slideshow loops unexpectedly when it first displays. After this it's fine and the images cycle normally.

Any help?

The result: http://colejohnsontrialsite.com/view.php

My Code:

```
<script>
    $("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

    setInterval(function() { 
       $('#slideshow > div:first')
       .fadeOut(1000)
       .next()
       .fadeIn(1000)
       .end()
       .appendTo('#slideshow');
    },  3000);
</script>

<div id="slideshow" style="float:left;">

<?php
   $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","username","pass","database_name");

   $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM gifs");


   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo ' <div> <img id="slideshow" src="' . $row['addresses'] . '">';  echo "</img></div>";
   }

   mysqli_close($con);
?>

</div>
```

Comment: use your code inside $(document).ready(function() { .... });

Comment: Whooops, thanks @Tamil Selvan. I was hoping for a simple fix like that. For reference, here is the different code that worked: `<script>
$(document).ready(function() { $("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

setInterval(function() { 
  $('#slideshow > div:first')
    .fadeOut(1000)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(1000)
    .end()
    .appendTo('#slideshow');
},  3000); });

   
  </script>`

Comment: You have got a lot of tag with id="slideshow". Your image container div and your image tags also have this. Try to correct this. I think you can delete them from the image tags.